# Calculate mean only for match strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, function

I have this assignment in which I have a file that contains alot of chromosed that I need to calculate for each one of them the mutation level.
The problem is that each chromosome can appear several times and I need to find the mean for all the mutation levels of this chromosome. and on top of that i need that the mutation will be in same nucleotides (T-->C or G-->A).
The mutation level is calculate by DP4 under INFO which contains four numbers that represented as [ref+,ref-,alt+,alt-]
Example of the file:

```
  #CHROM    POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
    chr1    143755378   .   T   C   62  .   DP=550;VDB=0;SGB=-0.693147;RPB=1.63509e-10;MQB=1;BQB=0.861856;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=0,108,0,440;MQ=20    GT:PL:DP    1/1:89,179,0:548
    chr3    57644487    .   T   C   16.4448 .   DP=300;VDB=0;SGB=-0.693147;RPB=0.993846;MQB=1;BQB=0.316525;MQ0F=0;ICB=1;HOB=0.5;AC=1;AN=2;DP4=0,166,0,134;MQ=20 GT:PL:DP    0/1:49,0,63:300
    chr3    80706912    .   T   C   212 .   DP=298;VDB=0;SGB=-0.693147;RPB=0.635135;MQB=1;MQSB=1;BQB=0.609797;MQ0F=0;AC=2;AN=2;DP4=1,1,256,40;MQ=20 GT:PL:DP    1/1:239,255,0:298
```

So this what I did until now and Im kinda stuck not really knowing how to continue from that point:

```
def vcf(file):
 with open(file, "r+") as my_file:
    """First I wanted to clear the headline"""
    for columns in my_file:
        if columns.startswith("#"):
            continue
        """Then I split the file into columns"""
        for columns in my_file:
            columns=columns.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
            """This is the info column"""
            for row in columns[7]:
                row = columns[7].split(";")
                """Using slicing I extracted the DP4 part and removed the str DP4"""
            DP4 = [row[-2]]
            new_DP4 = [x.replace("DP4=","") for x in DP4]
            """Then I took all the int outs and put them under the categories"""
            for x in new_DP4:
                xyz = x.split(",")
            ref_plus = int(xyz[0])
            ref_minus = int(xyz[1])
            alt_plus = int(xyz[2])
            alt_minus = int(xyz[3])
            """calculated the mean for each one"""
            formula = ((alt_minus+alt_plus)/(alt_minus+alt_plus+ref_minus+ref_plus))
            """made a list of the chromosomes and their means"""
            chr_form = [columns[0] , columns[3], columns[4], (formula)]
```

so basically I thought that now that I have all the data in list I can sort out somehow the same chr and do the means but I cant figure out how to do it.. I tried to use regex as well but im not that familiar with that
this is my current output for chr_form:

```
['chr3', 'T', 'C', 0.44666666666666666]
['chr3', 'T', 'C', 0.9932885906040269]
['chr5', 'A', 'G', 0.42073170731707316]
['chr5', 'A', 'G', 0.5772870662460567]
['chr6', 'A', 'G', 0.5153061224489796]
['chr6', 'A', 'G', 0.8934010152284264]
```

and so on..
but the output I want to get in the end is this:

```
{1: {‘T->C’: 0.802}, 3: {‘T->C’:0.446}}
```

I'll be happy to get an idea or example how to calculate the mean for each chr,

Comment: Stop reusing the `columns` variable, it's very confusing.

Comment: Why do you have nested `for columns in my_file:` loops? Also, a file is made up of rows or lines, a row is made up of columns.

Comment: Maybe you should use `pandas`.

Comment: Didn't noticed the nested loops, I'll change it. 
I still don't know how to use pandas and I'm trying to solve it with the tools I familiar with.

Comment: `for row in columns[7]:` why are you looping through the characters of a string, and repeatedly assigning the same variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lots of unnecessary `for` loops. The only loop you need is for the lines in the file, you don't need to loop over the characters in fields when you're splitting them or removing something from the whole field.

At the end, you should be adding the result of the calculation to a dictionary.

```
def vcf(file):
    chromosomes = {}
    with open(file, "r+") as my_file:
        # First I wanted to clear the headline
        for line in my_file:
            if line.startswith("#"): # skip comment lines.
                continue
            line=line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
            # This is the info column
            info = line[7].split(";")
            # Using slicing I extracted the DP4 part and removed the str DP4
            DP4 = info[-2].replace("DP4=","")
            # Then I took all the int outs and put them under the categories
            ref_plus, ref_minus, alt_plus, alt_minus = map(int, DP4.split(','))
            # calculated the mean for each one
            formula = ((alt_minus+alt_plus)/(alt_minus+alt_plus+ref_minus+ref_plus))
            # Get chromosome number from first field
            chr_num = int(line[0].replace('chr', ''))
            chromosomes[chr_num] = {f'{line[3]}->{line[4]}': formula}

    return chromosomes
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful.
Im still new so my work is a mess but I got good ideas from this on how to work better